# Declare end date as current date on below procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below procedure where I want to declare start and end date and statically pass `@fac_ids` inside, how can I edit the below procedure so that it takes the same date column for end date as current date?

The goal is to get the data set without manually passing the parameter while executing the procedure or create it as a view with passing start and end date (end date as current) and passing all the `fac_ids`.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sproc_ar_aging_new]    Script Date: 4/10/2020 1:18:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO        

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_ar_aging_new] @fac_ids varchar(8000) = null, @reference_date datetime
/********************************************************************************
Revision History:

Sample Execution Script:
EXEC dbo.sproc_ar_aging @fac_ids = '8', @reference_date= '20140801';
**********************************************************************************/   
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY

DECLARE
         @month int
        ,@year int
        ,@Status_Text varchar(1000)

SELECT  SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2.effective_date <  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date) OR (Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date)  AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_date <  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date))  THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_tot, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date)   AND (Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_type =  'C'   OR Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_type IS NULL ) AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_date <  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date)   THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_future_cash, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  @reference_date   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date < dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date) --'2010-09-01 00:00:00:000'   
                OR (Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_date <  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_type <>  'C'  )  THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_0, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -1, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  @reference_date   THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_1, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -2, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  dateadd(month, -1, @reference_date)   THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_2, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -3, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  dateadd(month, -2, @reference_date)   THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_3, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -4, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  dateadd(month, -3, @reference_date)   THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_4, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -5, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  dateadd(month, -4, @reference_date)   THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_5, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -6, @reference_date)   AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  dateadd(month, -5, @reference_date)  THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_6, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .effective_date <  dateadd(month, -6, @reference_date)  THEN Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_7, 
        mpi.last_name, mpi.first_name, client.client_id_number, Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .client_id, client.discharge_date, client.admission_date, Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .payer_id, libpayer.payer_code, libpayer.payer_code2, libpayer.description AS payer_desc, client.fac_id 
    INTO #Temp

FROM 
--Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 _rollup
(
select transaction_id,   
    -1 AS applied_payment_id,   
    fac_id,   
    client_id,   
    payer_id,   
    -1 AS batch_id,   
    -1 AS invoice_id,   
    -1 AS dollars_account_id,   
    transaction_type,  
    transaction_date,   
    -1 AS entry_number,   
    -1 AS cash_receipt_number,   
    effective_date,   
    amount,   
    NULL AS trial_invoice_id,  
    t.effective_date as trunc_effective_date,   
    t.transaction_date as trunc_transaction_date,  
    convert(int, null) as distribution_tx_id,  

       convert(bit, 1) as is_billed  
FROM dbo.ar_transactions_rollup_client AS t  
union all  
SELECT t.transaction_id,   
       (CASE WHEN t .transaction_type = 'C' THEN h.applied_payment_id ELSE - 1 END) AS applied_payment_id,   
    t.fac_id,   
    t.client_id,   
    t.payer_id,   
    t.batch_id,   
    t.invoice_id,   
    t.dollars_account_id,   
    t.transaction_type,   
    t.transaction_date,   
    t.entry_number,   
    NULL AS cash_receipt_number,   
    (CASE WHEN t .transaction_type = 'C' THEN h.applied_to_date ELSE t .effective_date END) AS effective_date,   
       (CASE WHEN t .transaction_type = 'C' THEN - 1 * h.amount ELSE t .amount END) AS amount,   
    t.trial_invoice_id,  
    -- Truncate effective_date to the 15th of the month like the rollup table.  
    cast(convert(varchar(7), (CASE WHEN t .transaction_type = 'C'   
                              THEN h.applied_to_date   
         ELSE t .effective_date END), 126)+'-15' as datetime) as trunc_effective_date,  
    -- Truncate transaction_date to the 15th of the month like the rollup table.  
    cast(convert(varchar(7),t.transaction_date,126)+'-15' as datetime) as trunc_transaction_date,  
       t.distribution_tx_id,  
       convert(bit, case when t.invoice_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_billed  
FROM dbo.ar_transactions AS t   
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ar_applied_payment_history AS h   
            ON h.transaction_id = t.transaction_id   
            AND h.fac_id = t.fac_id   
      AND ISNULL(h.deleted, 'N') = 'N'   
      AND h.current_period_date IS NOT NULL  
WHERE t.deleted = 'N'   
      AND t.client_id > 0   
   AND t.payer_id > 0   
   AND t.transaction_date IS NOT NULL   
   AND t.OpenClose_Flag = 'O'  
union all  
SELECT transaction_id,   
       applied_payment_id,   
    fac_id,  
    client_id,   
    payer_id,  
    NULL AS batch_id,   
    NULL AS invoice_id,   
    NULL AS dollars_account_id,  
    NULL AS transaction_type,   
    current_period_date AS transaction_date,   
    NULL AS entry_number,   
    NULL AS cash_receipt_number,   
    applied_to_date AS effective_date,   
    - (1 * amount) AS amount,   
    NULL AS trial_invoice_id,  
    -- Truncate effective_date to the 15th of the month like the rollup table.  
    cast(convert(varchar(7),h.applied_to_date,126)+'-15' as datetime) as trunc_effective_date,  
    -- Truncate transaction_date to the 15th of the month like the rollup table.  
    cast(convert(varchar(7),h.current_period_date,126)+'-15' as datetime) as trunc_transaction_date,  
       -1 as distribution_tx_id,  
       convert(bit, 0) as is_billed  
FROM dbo.ar_applied_payment_history AS h  
WHERE deleted = 'N'   
      AND client_id > 0   
   AND payer_id > 0   
   AND transaction_id = -1   
   AND OpenClose_Flag = 'O'  
)Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2  
LEFT JOIN dbo.CLIENTS client 
    ON Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .client_id = client.client_id 
    AND (client.deleted = 'N')  
LEFT JOIN dbo.MPI mpi 
    ON client.mpi_id = mpi.mpi_id 
    AND (mpi.deleted = 'N')  
LEFT JOIN dbo.AR_PAYERS payer 
    ON Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .payer_id = payer.payer_id 
    AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .fac_id = payer.fac_id 
LEFT JOIN dbo.AR_LIB_PAYERS libpayer 
    ON Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .payer_id = libpayer.payer_id 
    AND (libpayer.deleted = 'N')  
WHERE Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_id IS NOT NULL  
AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .transaction_date  <  dateadd(month, 1, @reference_date)  
AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount IS NOT NULL  
AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .amount  <>  0 
AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .client_id  >  0  
AND Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .payer_id  IN (SELECT AR_PAYERS.PAYER_ID 
                                FROM dbo.AR_PAYERS 
                                LEFT JOIN dbo.AR_LIB_PAYERS libpayer 
                                    ON AR_PAYERS.payer_id = libpayer.payer_id 
                                    AND libpayer.deleted = 'N'  
                                WHERE (libpayer.payer_type IS NULL  OR libpayer.payer_type  <>  'Medicare D' ) 
                                        AND (AR_PAYERS.FAC_ID =  Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .FAC_ID  OR AR_PAYERS.FAC_ID = -1))

AND (Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .fac_id in (select convert(int,items) from Split(@fac_ids,',')) OR @fac_ids is null)

GROUP BY mpi.last_name, mpi.first_name, client.client_id_number, Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .client_id, client.discharge_date, client.admission_date, Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .payer_id, libpayer.payer_code, libpayer.payer_code2, libpayer.description , client.fac_id 
--ORDER BY  mpi.last_name, mpi.first_name, client.client_id_number, Pcc_view_ar_aging_rollup2 .client_id, client.discharge_date, client.admission_date, libpayer.payer_code, libpayer.payer_code2, libpayer.description

select  0 as IndexNumber, f.facility_code as FacilityCode , f.name Facility, t.last_name +' '+ t.first_name + ' ('+t.client_id_number+')' as ClientName,
        case when t.payer_code2 != '' then t.payer_code + '-' + t.payer_code2 else t.payer_code end as Payer,
        sum_bucket_tot as Total,
        sum_bucket_future_cash as FutureCash,
        sum_bucket_0 as [Current],
        sum_bucket_1 as [30 days],
        sum_bucket_2 as [60 days],
        sum_bucket_3 as [90 days],
        sum_bucket_4 as [120 days],
        sum_bucket_5 as [150 days],
        sum_bucket_6 as [180 days],
        sum_bucket_7 as [210 days +]
from #temp t
join dbo.facility f on f.fac_id = t.fac_id
where (sum_bucket_tot != 0 
        or sum_bucket_0  != 0
        or sum_bucket_1  != 0 
        or sum_bucket_2  != 0
        or sum_bucket_3  != 0
        or sum_bucket_4  != 0
        or sum_bucket_5  != 0
        or sum_bucket_6  != 0
        or sum_bucket_7 != 0 )

union
select  1, f.facility_code, f.name, t.payer_desc ,
        case when t.payer_code2 != '' then t.payer_code + '-' + t.payer_code2 else t.payer_code end ,
        sum(sum_bucket_tot),
        sum(sum_bucket_future_cash),
        sum(sum_bucket_0),
        sum(sum_bucket_1),
        sum(sum_bucket_2),
        sum(sum_bucket_3),
        sum(sum_bucket_4),
        sum(sum_bucket_5),
        sum(sum_bucket_6),
        sum(sum_bucket_7)
from #temp t
join dbo.facility f on f.fac_id = t.fac_id
where (sum_bucket_tot != 0 
        or sum_bucket_0  != 0
        or sum_bucket_1  != 0 
        or sum_bucket_2  != 0
        or sum_bucket_3  != 0
        or sum_bucket_4  != 0
        or sum_bucket_5  != 0
        or sum_bucket_6  != 0
        or sum_bucket_7 != 0 )

group by f.facility_code, f.name, t.payer_desc,
        case when t.payer_code2 != '' then t.payer_code + '-' + t.payer_code2 else t.payer_code end
ORDER BY 1, f.facility_code, f.name, t.last_name +' '+ t.first_name + ' ('+t.client_id_number+')',
        case when t.payer_code2 != '' then t.payer_code + '-' + t.payer_code2 else t.payer_code end;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp;
END


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT @Status_Text = RTRIM(LEFT('Stored Procedure Failed with error Code : ' +   CAST(@@error AS varchar(10)) +  ' Line Number : ' +  CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS varchar(5)) + ' ' +  ERROR_MESSAGE(),1000))
    RAISERROR( @Status_Text, 11, 1 );

END CATCH
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @enddate datetime;
SET @enddate = (SELECT GETDATE());
```

Comment: Hi @Gark, Welcome to SO. It is always better to provide short description of code how it is solving the problem :)